# What are the best steps to improve magento performance?

Tags: performance, magento

I have a magento shop (ver 1.2) running under a dedicated LAMP setup.

I have made the following changes to it:

- Enabled magento caching
- Enabled APC
- MySQL Query caching
- GZip compression of html,css,js

The shop is still incredibly slow, around 10 secs and over for rendering the homepage. Is there any obvious things I am missing out.

Please share your tips to improve Magento performance

Answer (score 5):

Our biggest speed increase came from placing ./magento/var/cache onto a tmpfs filesystem.

We also moved the contents of the .htaccess files into the Apache configuration. That eliminated checking for the file each page hit.

We enabled gzip compression on the server too. It seemed to help a bit.

You may also want to check out your MySQL query cache config.

There are a few guides to tuning your Magento install online. I liked this one: http://www.neurosoftware.ro/programming-blog/blogposter/web-resources/magento-performance-hosting/

Answer (score 3):

I do a few things that on their own won't make much difference, but combined can make a substantial difference.

1) gzip compression
2) minify HTML, CSS, JSS (remove all unneccessary white space)
3) Optimise your images
4) Disable any unused modules
5) Combine external CSS/JS into one file
6) Cache files that can be cached

The .htaccess trick mentioned above sounds quite good. I've never tried it but will be trying at work on Monday!

Comment: The .htaccess trick worked for me, but not a huge improvement as i had hoped :(

We make heavy use of caching on the site so im going to try moving /var to memory to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use caching extension MTurbo http://www.artio.net/magento-extensions/m-turbo-accelerator

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest switching to the [Litespeed webserver](http://www.litespeedtech.com/overview.html), it works with Magento without any configuration (apart from setting up PHP of course), and gives a huge performance boost. Failing that try switching PHP into fast-cgi mode.

Answer (score 2):

My biggest performance increase came from installing Xcache to cache the code at php level,
turning on mysql query caching will help too as alot of similar queries are requested from the mysql server in the same page request