# Magento Performance Tuning

Tags: magento, performance

I have a server which is running more than 15 Magento stores, but they are not performing well, though I have a giant server for hosting them. My server configuration is - 8 CPU's Quad Core 24GB RAM and 2 TB HDD.

My current page load is 1.6sec. I want it under 600ms. I have already installed APC, & eAccelerator and tuned Apache's parameters. I am using the latest Magento version.

Please suggest.

-Ramesh

Comment: You want fast disks over large disks.

Comment: To the people voting to close, Magento optimization is usually more of a code optimization than hardware, so this is probably valid. See previous similar posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you will see a benefit of using APC and eAccelerator on the same server.  They pretty much do the same thing.

A page load of 1.6 seconds is fairly typical for a Magento install. They easiest way to lower your page load time (after basic Apache and MySQL tuning and APC) is use a Full Page Cache.  There are a few out on the market right now.  We have written a Full Page Cache that has gotten page loads down to the .1 - .3 second range for most users, http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/performance/full-page-cache-magento.html

Answer (score 2):

You might look at enabling block caching as explained [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput). It should work pretty well on the category and product pages but you have to be extra careful to apply proper cache tags and identifiers to make sure the content you are displaying is always up to date...

Answer (score 2):

First things first, what is actually bottlenecked? Optimization is always about tradeoffs, and you may just make things worse if you're looking in the wrong places. Make use of `top` (assuming you're on Linux here) and see what your processor/memory usage look like.

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and say that, if you have already added an opcode, you may be waiting on other HTTP requests for page load. Use YSlow on Firefox and see if you are trying to load excessive amounts of data. Optimizing image size and setting proper caching parameters for images may solve the problem there.

If not, silvo's suggestion is a very good one. Using either block-level or page-level caching can really speed up a site. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow) [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858012/techniques-to-speed-up-magento-on-a-shared-host) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403184/what-are-the-best-steps-to-improve-magento-performance) been covered previously, so see those posts, too.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe