# Magento: how to debug "admin"?

Tags: mysql, debugging, magento, magento-1.5

In whole I have two questions where one follows from other.

I tried to run magento under linux and windows. 
Under linux base configuration works perfect.
Under windows - doesn't. Every page is loaded about 20-30 sec., especially in admin panel.

So here are two questions.

1) I'd appreciate if someone posts some links about magento optimization.

2) How to debug admin panel? (it is like profiler for frontend with:

```
Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: check to see if you have apc active for your windows install, magento is a huge resource hog.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403184/what-are-the-best-steps-to-improve-magento-performance

Comment: Tnx for the link! I don't understand about apc active a bit. Could you give some tips here please?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8937/

Comment: @Elzo Valugi. Could you set the first link as an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento is a big resource hog and some recommended actions are:

- Enabled magento caching
- Enabled APC
- MySQL Query caching
- GZip compression of html,css,js

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403184/what-are-the-best-steps-to-improve-magento-performance).