# Magento admin backend is very slow even with fresh installation

Tags: magento, slowdown, performance

The Magento admin backend is very slow with fresh installation of the same version 1.7.0.2.

With my previous installation, it was working perfectly fine with reasonably good speed on the same server with same hosting company and no additional tweaks at all.

But suddenly I messed up with it due to another custom theme that I installed. So I reinstalled it after removing it. Then I found more problems in even accessing it.

Hence, I created new `public_html` folder and rename the previous one to `public_html.old`.

Then I was able to reinstall the Magento successfully on the root folder. But this time it is opening very very slow, in fact, every step is slow.

Can anybody help me to trace the actual reason. What could be the possibilities. It was working fine earlier but why not this time.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old issue, but many people are still using 1.7.0.2, so I think it's still relevant.

The performance lag described makes the system unusable, and it's definitely not just the standard tweaks that can fix it. It's a bug with such an easy "work around" if you can call it that, that fixing it was likely a low priority. But I didn't find this work around easily.  So I'm posting here.

**My Setup:**

- MacBook Pro
- Vagrant set with NFS on VirtualBox
- VM of Ubuntu 12.4
- LAMP
- Magento 1.7.0.2
- Adequate RAM etc

**The Issue**
I was getting 8 to 12 second page loads on the admin interface.  Typical performance when working right was about 1 second loads.

**Diagnosis**
*I ran the Magento Profiler:* see http://www.neptuneweb.com/blog/?id=24

- First, enable the profiler via System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Profile (yes). This enables the profiler, but does not fill in any of the benchmark times.
- Find the commented out line in /index.php around line 71
- Uncomment this line to enable profiler. "Varien_Profiler::enable();"
- Refresh the page you are optimizing. At the bottom of the page, you will see the performance table.

In my case, the profiler table (not sortable unfortunately) showed very late times for the "adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/survey.phtml"

It seems to show you a time stamp starting at 0 when the request comes in, to whatever mark for each tracked event. In this way, you can't see how long something took to process and return. But you can tell when it finished and by subtracting the next highest time of a different process, you can (kind of) tell how long it took. Likely there is some asymmetrical processing going on to complicate things. But since some probably have dependencies they wait on, this seems to work ok.

**Solution**

- Upon loading the admin interface again, I noticed the nag bar on top asking me to fill out a survey to send back to Magento.  Upon dismissing that notice, everything became quick...

So, it was a painfully easy resolution for me after much troubleshooting.  But if that's not that exact cause for you, or the popup doesn't appear, the troubleshooting info should help find what is.

The profiler is also a great tool to help optimize page loads even when it's working more or less ok.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've turned the Compilation on: admin> System-Tools-Compilation. This can boost the performance.

There's a similar [thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/264175/#t402302) at Magento community forum and a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403184/what-are-the-best-steps-to-improve-magento-performance/12641438#12641438) at stackoverflow.

Comment: I will do this and let you know. Thanks for your kind response. By the way what did compilation do. As the developer of custom theme suggests to disable compilation prior to theme installation. What is it's actual role in frontend and backend both.

Comment: Compilation allows to compile all files of a Magento installation in order to create a single include path. it should decrease page load times.  But as to your back end, remember to disable compilation if you're modifying the Magento installation, then when it's done, you can turn it on again.

If you have byte code caching enabled, you can turn compilation off.

Comment: by "Modifying Magento installation", do you mean by "Creating Categories, Products, Attributes, tags" or some other modifications.
Is it MUST to Disable compiler while we create Categories, products or by installing new THEME everytime, or we can put it on Enable status during this time.

Comment: Also, can you please let me know about "Byte code caching", where can i find it and how it is related to compilation.

Comment: Actually, modifications to the installation means installing new themes, extensions etc. In this case you need to make sure the compilation is disabled, but after the process is completed, you can turn compilation on. As to bytecode caching, by default APC cache is used. This is a way of speeding up Magento, so if you're using this, you don't really need compilation.

Comment: Does modification includes somehow creating new categories and products also, or we can enable compilation during product and category creation.
APC, this is what I heard of, many times, can you please let me know about this. It's benefits and its features.

Comment: Does enabling compilation increases boost in speed at both backend and frontend.
How to enable byte code caching, where can i find the option.

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to find the info at Magento Connect,     you'll find tutorials and the needed answers.

Comment: Sure, never mind, will look into that. Thanks for helping me out as much as you can

Comment: My experience has been to install Redis Cache for the backend of Magento, it was quite successfull.